# How to profile macro finder

Tags: macros, z3

The macro finder is a very useful option but it seems to blow up occasionally. Is there a way to profile the macro finder to see what macro is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not directly. You can run z3 with `-v:10` to get some additional output indicating what the solver is doing and that may give you a first indication of where things go wrong. You can also run the macro-finder tactic separately (replace `check-sat` with `(apply (then simplify macro-finder))` or similar) to make sure that it's in fact the macro-finder that blows up. In debug mode you can also enable the macro-finder trace via `-tr:macro_finder` and it will then print various bits of information into a file called `.z3-trace`. This only works in debug mode though, so you'll have to compile your own binary.